# Empty row after each record and columns in newline

Tags: awk

I have a file with variable columns what looks like this:

```
text11|text12|text13 text121|text122|text123 text131|text132|text133
text21|text22|text23 text221|text222|text223 text231|text232|text233 text241|text242|text243
```

What I want is that :

1. each column should be on a new line
2. pipe should be replaced by space
3. and after each record of the original file there should be an empty line

like this:

```
text11  text12  text13 
text121 text122 text123 
text131 text132 text133

text21  text22   text23 
text221 text222 text223
text231 text232 text233
text241 text242 text243
```

Is there a way to do this with only awk?

I tried something like this:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'gsub(" ","\n"); gsub("\n", "\n\n",$NR)'
```

but that does not work of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, non idiomatic, approach might be this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/\|/, " ", $i);print $i} print ""}' file
```

Explanation:

```
{
    # Iterate through the input fields, which are split by space
    # Note: NF is the number of input fields
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        # replace all pipes by space
        gsub(/\|/, " ", $i)
        # and print
        print $i
    }
    # Additional newline
    print "" 
}
```

Comment: No this does not give the extra empty line after each record

Comment: I've tested it with the example data which you posted here. Can it be that your input file is using windows line endings?

Comment: When i check it with vi and option [:set list] a see a $ at the end of each line.

Comment: When the file has consistent windows line endings, vi would display them as `$`, as it would do with UNIX line endings. Therefore it's not a good indicator. Can you run `sed 's/\r//' input_file > temp_file` and run my awk command on that temp file?

Comment: Same. by the way I see that my awk linked to nawk in ubuntu 19.10. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Yeah, that might be. Let me test it with `nawk`

Comment: hmm installed gawk, that does not work. Then the last hope is my zsh. For some reason I can't switch to bash. Could you try with zsh?

Comment: What I can say for sure, It's not related to the shell. I'm very surprised that `gawk` doesn't work, because that's what I'm using too

Comment: Btw, just tested with `nawk`, that works for me as well. There must be something special with your input file, which is not contained within the example you posted.

Comment: I just created the same file as the example above with vi. That is also not showing the extra empty line. I am using default zsh shell. I had a similar problem with a bash script before but can't relate what the solution was.

Comment: I also tested this on a centos server with bash and gawk. Looks like you version of the file has a space before the end of the line of the first line. If you remove that it does not work. Could you verify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206781/discussion-between-geveze-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: I have not much time to chat because I'm at work. I'll check that newline at the end

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it, changed my answer. I admit I didn't expect this, whitespace at the end or not

Comment: thanks for the hint! The answer was indeed non-sense, changed it!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");gsub(FS,ORS);gsub(/\|/,OFS)} 1'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");gsub(/ /,ORS);gsub(/\|/,OFS)} 1'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");gsub(/ /,"\n");gsub(/\|/,OFS)} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code. This is only for explanation purposes.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
{                  ##Starting main BLOCK of program from here.
  gsub(FS,ORS)     ##Globally substituting spaces with new lines here.
  gsub(/\|/,OFS)   ##Globally substituting pipe with space for all occurrences of current line.
}                  ##Closing main BLOCK of this line here.
1                  ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
'  Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I don't get the extra empty line after each record. I am suspicous about ubuntu's awk what is linked to nawk.

Comment: @Geveze, So you mean it didn't give output as per your shown results? For me checked on bash it worked fine and provided results as per your shown output.

Comment: Correct. I guess zsh is acting different than bash on awk commands.

Comment: @Geveze, Could you please check my codes now? I have added logic of removing control M characters in them too, not sure but there may be a chance of control M in your files. You could check with `cat -v Input_file` command too, lemme know how it goes then?

Comment: Same. Also with cat -v

Comment: Looks like in my post there was a space at te end of the first line. That's why its working for you. If you remove that it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Another, difference probably in `gsub(/$/,"\n")`:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ /,"\n");gsub(/\|/," ");sub(/$/,"\n")}1' file
```

Output:

```
text11 text12 text13
text121 text122 text123
text131 text132 text133

text21 text22 text23
text221 text222 text223
text231 text232 text233
text241 text242 text243
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v ORS='\n\n' '{gsub(FS,RS); gsub(/\|/,OFS)} 1' file
text11 text12 text13
text121 text122 text123
text131 text132 text133

text21 text22 text23
text221 text222 text223
text231 text232 text233
text241 text242 text243
```